# Converting a complex JSON object into a C# property

Tags: c#, json

I am struggling to build a complex JSON object this is what I want:

```
{"name": [ "failed","complete"], "data": ["failed":[1, 2, 3], "completed": [1, 2, 3]}
```

I want to convert this in a C# class as a property. There must be a connection with the failed property and the list of int. The output must be:

failed: 1, 2, 3
complete: 1,2 ,3

What is the correct syntax of a JSON object like this? And how can I declare a property of this object in c#?

I was thinking about dictionaries but maybe there is a better way?

Kind regards

Comment: That's not valid json, so you'll have to write your own interpreter.

Comment: Assuming you fix the missing `]`, in Visual Studio: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste as JSON Classes.

Comment: @crashmstr like this? `{"name": [ "failed","complete"], "data": ["failed":[1, 2, 3], "completed": [1, 2, 3]]}`

Comment: If `data` is an array of objects, you need `{
    "name": [
        "failed",
        "complete"
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "failed": [ ... ],
            "completed": [ ... ]
        }
    ]
}`, if `data` is a single object, `{
    "name": [
        "failed",
        "complete"
    ],
    "data": {
        "failed": [ ... ],
        "completed": [ ... ]
    }
}`

Comment: You can use some online json class converter and NewtonSoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be :

```
{"name": [ "failed","complete"], "data": {"failed":[1, 2, 3], "completed": [1, 2, 3]}}
```

then you can use :

```
public class Data {
    public List<int> failed { get; set; }
    public List<int> completed { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject {
    public List<string> name { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

and for any json to c#, I use : 
[json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)

**EDIT:**
I think, a better approach for your case is using dictionary and following class:

```
public class DataValues {
    public List<int> Data;
}
```

and then use it like :

```
Dictionary<string, DataValues> x = new Dictionary<string, DataValues>();

x.Add("failed", new DataValues() {
    Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
});
x.Add("complete", new DataValues() {
    Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
});

var resultinJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(x);
```

Then, the Json result is :

```
{
    "failed": {
        "Data": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    "complete": {
        "Data": [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

obviously, you can add more `status` or `step` or what ever it is called in your `app.` to it.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I am looking for have a nice day!